# How can I check if a vector is a subsequence (in the same order but not contiguous) of another vector?

Tags: algorithm, rust, iterator

How can I check if all elements of `vector_a` also appear in the same order as `vector_b`?

`vector_b` could be very long, there is no assumption that it is sorted, but it does not have duplicate elements.

I could not find a method implemented for `Vec` or in itertools, so I tried implementing by doing:

1. Create a hashmap from `vector_b` mapping `value -> index`
2. Iterate over `vector_b` and check that:

   - Element exists in hashmap
   - Index is strictly greater than previous element's index

I am not really happy with this as it is not space efficient due to the creation of the hashmap.

Comment: You can simply do a linear search for the first element of `vector_a` in `vector_b`. Once you found it, search for the next one, and so on. Since `vector_b` does not have duplicates, you never need to back up again, so this is linear in the length of `vector_b`, and only needs constant additional space.

Comment: A simple possible optimisation is to exit the loop once there are more remaining elements in `vector_a` than in `vector_b`, because then it's not possible anymore to find all of them.

Comment: Does this need to be generic over the vector elements, or are the elements a specific type?

Comment: @PeterHall The elements are another struct that derives from `Copy`, `Eq` and `PartialEq`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, thanks for the suggestion. I can do this. Would you recommend this method: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position for searching? My doubt was, for an unsorted `vector_b`, the searching might end up being very inefficient WRT time?

Comment: Small clarification: given `a = [1, 2]` and `b = [1, 0, 2]`, should the algorithm return `true` or `false` (`b` does contain the same elements as `a` in the same order)? Or should the elements of `a` be contiguous inside `b`?

Comment: @Jmb Exactly, it should return `true`. Being contiguous is not required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for each element of the needle in the haystack in order. Each time you find a matching element, only continue the search in the remaining portion of the haystack. You can express this nicely by taking a new subslice of of the haystack each time you match an element.

```
fn is_subsequence<T: PartialEq>(needle: &[T], mut haystack: &[T]) -> bool {
    for search in needle {
        if let Some(index) = haystack.iter().position(|el| search == el) {
            haystack = &haystack[index + 1..];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}

assert!(is_subsequence(b"", b"0123456789"));
assert!(is_subsequence(b"0", b"0123456789"));
assert!(is_subsequence(b"059", b"0123456789"));
assert!(is_subsequence(b"345", b"0123456789"));
assert!(is_subsequence(b"0123456789", b"0123456789"));

assert!(!is_subsequence(b"335", b"0123456789"));
assert!(!is_subsequence(b"543", b"0123456789"));
```

A slice is just a pointer and a size, stored on the stack, so this does no new allocations. It runs in `O(n)` time and should be close to the fastest possible implementation - or at least in the same ballpark.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. What could be the consequences of making `haystack` a mutable reference? I believe if this must be part of a library, then allowing immutable reference would be preferred, right?

Comment: @user2774555 `haystack` is not a mutable reference. Only the local variable is mutable (it gets reassigned with smaller and smaller subslices), but the original slice cannot be mutated: that would require the argument to be `haystack: &mut [T]`.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to do it is to iterate the two vectors jointly:

```
fn contains<T: PartialEq>(needle: &[T], haystack: &[T]) -> bool {
    let mut idx = 0;
    for it in needle {
        while (idx < haystack.len()) && (&haystack[idx] != it) {
            idx += 1;
        }
        if idx == haystack.len() {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```